# java scanner.hasnext regex not working as expected

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use a scanner to validate input on a simple CLI tool. The string can only contain letters, numbers and a forward slash. The regex that I have used `^[a-zA-Z0-9/]+$` works when I test it on http://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String path = "";
    String domain = "";


    System.out.print("domain (eg. example.com):");
    while (!sc.hasNext("(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\\d+\\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]{1,63}\\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)")) {
        System.out.println("invalid domain name.");
        sc.next();
    }
    domain = sc.next();



    System.out.print("path:");
    while (!sc.hasNext("^[a-zA-Z0-9/]+$")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid path. Try again:");
        sc.next();
    }
    path = sc.next();

}

}
```

Here is the output from my program:

```
domain (eg. example.com):si.com
path:/one/two/three
Invalid path. Try again:
/
Invalid path. Try again:
/one/two
Invalid path. Try again:
aaa
Invalid path. Try again:
```

Edit: The code above doesn't produce a match on strings such as `/one/two`, `/one` or `/`.

What am I doing wrong? 
Is my regex correct?
Why is it the tester that I linked to produces different results?

Comment: Yes it has: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext-java.util.regex.Pattern-

Comment: Good point @CollinD, I should know better :)

Comment: @Koekje I don't follow what you are saying... can you elaborate?

Comment: Could you please be more precise about how your program’s observed behaviour differs from the desired? A sample run with input and output may be good for understanding.

Comment: @simon It was a reponse to a now removed comment stating that there is no hasNext method accepting parameters, which is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex that you are using has a NOT ^ in the beginning. Because of that the regex is rejecting the path. Please try the following code.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("path:");
    while (!scanner.hasNext("[a-zA-Z0-9/]+")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid path. Try again:");
        scanner.next();
    }
    String path = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("path:"+path);
```

It should work

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was missing.

Comment: I think that the `^` as the first character of the pattern doesn’t mean ‘not’, but rather ‘the beginning of a line’. However, it does prevent a match from happening except at the beginning of the input, so the user never gets a second chance to get the input right. You were correct in that we needed to have it removed.

Comment: If the ^ was inside ()  or in the regular expression out of the []....The behaviour that you have described is accurate.....PS all these are with respect to regex in java